# How to get name of requested controller and action in middleware Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel, and i want to get name of requested controller and action in beforefilter middelware.

Thanks,
DJ

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Laravel 5.6:**

```phph
class_basename(Route::current()->controller);
```

**Laravel 5.5 and lower:**

You can retrieve the current action name with `Route::currentRouteAction()`. Unfortunately, this method will return a fully namespaced class name. So you will get something like:

```
App\Http\Controllers\FooBarController@method
```

Then just separate method name and controller name:

```php
$currentAction = \Route::currentRouteAction();
list($controller, $method) = explode('@', $currentAction);
// $controller now is "App\Http\Controllers\FooBarController"

$controller = preg_replace('/.*\\\/', '', $controller);
// $controller now is "FooBarController"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if laravel has a inbuilt function for this, because it wil be an costly operation to do this for every request....

Comment: There's no inbuilt functions for this as far as I know.

Comment: @limonte That is correct, there's no method implemented. In fact the `runController` method in `Illuminate\Routing\Route` uses `explode` in exactly the same way to determine the `$class` and `$method` that needs to be executed for the matched route.

Comment: `class_basename(Route::current()->controller)` would also do the trick. L5.6 tested

Comment: hey can you tell me how can i get the all method of this controller.

Comment: Any suggestion for Lumen 8?

Answer (score 6):

You can add this (Laravel v7 and above )

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
....
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionMethod()
```

Comment: `<?php echo request()->route()->getActionMethod(); ?>` you can also use as like this Helper function

Answer (score 1):

## Laravel 9

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#accessing-the-current-route

> Accessing The Current Route You may use the current, currentRouteName,
> and currentRouteAction methods on the Route facade to access
> information about the route handling the incoming request:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
>  
> $route = Route::current(); // Illuminate\Routing\Route
> $name = Route::currentRouteName(); // string
> $action = Route::currentRouteAction(); // string
> ```