# How can i get resource store route laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

My Add form code

```
<form method="post" name="m_form" action="{{url('post')}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="zL9O2D3H70fkSrt9vziwbkf2bHBqi6O6NKk1QgQK">
    <input type="text" required="" name="name" id="name" class="form-control m-input" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<form>
```

My Route

```
Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
```

Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $nextRequest = $next($request);
    dd($request->route()->getAction());
}
```

Now in Middleware **$request->route()->getAction()** is null

Now I want controller name and method name dynamically here all other route working fine but store route not found

Can you please guide me where I can make mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Laravel Log Class to log values in the log (/storage/logs/filename.log) file to watch the output.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class CheckControllerAction
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $action = Route::current()->action;
        $route = $action['uses'];
        $controllerAction = explode("@", $route);

        Log::info(class_basename($controllerAction[0]));
        Log::info($controllerAction[1]);
        Log::info(class_basename(Route::current()->controller));
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The output in the log file is:

```
[2018-12-04 21:34:41] local.INFO: PostController  
[2018-12-04 21:34:41] local.INFO: create  
[2018-12-04 21:34:41] local.INFO: PostController
```

Comment: `Route::current()` is null

Comment: @BhargavPatel, I have added the whole middleware and now check your code. you might be using a different class

Comment: @BhargavPatel, this is developed and tested on laravel 5.7

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.....

[How to get name of requested controller and action in middleware Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442746/how-to-get-name-of-requested-controller-and-action-in-middleware-laravel)

And just an FYI, you shouldn't be setting the _token using hard code, as in your example, but using Form::open(), as this sets the _token for you each time the page is loaded.  It's a much more secure way to ensure the _token cannot be forced, as opposed to your hard coded version which will obviously set the _token to the same value for all users, everytime.

Comment: For display complete form I write token but I use token as you said. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: I see your reference url but it's not working.

    `$controller = class_basename(Route::current());
    dd($controller);`

it's return null

Comment: The link posted above returns the property CONTROLLER from the Route::current() object.  PLease try and copy the code appropriate to the version of Laravel you are using.  For 5.6 it will be class_basename(Route::current()->controller)