# How to get name of requested controller and method name in middleware only, not in contoller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, middleware

I read this:
[How to get name of requested controller and action in middleware Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442746/how-to-get-name-of-requested-controller-and-action-in-middleware-laravel)
But it doesn't work in middleware in Laravel 9.
Here is code web.php:

```
Route::get('/debug',"App\Http\Controllers\DebugController@getDebug");
```

And also here is middleware:

```
class CheckIt
{
    
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        $routes = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName();
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I got the error:

```
Call to a member function getActionName() on null
```

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#accessing-the-current-route

Comment: $route = Route::current(); // Illuminate\Routing\Route
        $name = Route::currentRouteName(); // string
        $action = Route::currentRouteAction(); // string
        dump($route);
        dump($name);
        dd($action);
        null ,null, null all of this in middleware

Comment: What namespace does your middleware use for the Route?

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Comment: is this a route middleware or a global middleware?

Comment: Yes, it's global